# Android Lollipop App Installation Error : Duplicate C2D_MESSAGE permission error without declaring it

Tags: android, permissions

In my app I declare 3 permissions in Manifest file, but no C2D_MESSAGE permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

My app doesn't even use cloud messaging (C2D).
It works fine on Nougat but won't install on Lollipop because of "duplicate permission" error.

> W/PackageManager( 1196): Package com.app.package
>   attempting to redeclare permission
>   com.app.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE already owned by
>   com.app.package

When searching for C2D_MESSAGE I find it in a generated class file :

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE. DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
    public final class Manifest {
      public static final class permission {
        public static final String C2D_MESSAGE="com.app.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE";
      }

    }
```

- I found [this](https://mobikul.com/fix_install_failed_duplicate_permission_issue/), but again I don't have C2D_MESSAGE in manifest file (this site also says "This is issue commonly comes in <5.1 version.")
- Since C2D means Cloud to Device the only reason I can think of is Crashlytics (but that would rather be Device 2 Cloud though) . Could this cause the error ?

Why do I get a duplicate permission error of a permission I haven't declared ?

Comment: It most likely comes from your dependencies. If you look at the merged AndroidManifest.xml in your app/build directory you will see that the permission is there (came from a library you depend on).

Comment: I've searched for generated Manifest files : /app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml. It has entries of 'firebase' with references to C2DM_.. . But I will go the easy route and set min_sdk to v5.1. Anyway, Thanks !